# Wordpress.org The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have set up a new website, and besides the home page, all pages have this error:

> Not Found The requested URL XXXXXX was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at http://www.XXXXXXX.com Port 80

My htaccessfile looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Please note: I have very very low backend knowledge (I dont know how to access any backend files)

Comment: Try saving your permalinks again (Settings > Permalinks).

Comment: @cabrerahector Thanks for your reply! When I use wordpress's default permalinks everything works, but I want a custom permalink...?

Comment: Change back to your custom permalink structure, then click on Save Changes a couple of times to make sure WordPress rebuilds its permalinks cache and check again.

Comment: @cabrerahector nope.. that did not work :(

Comment: What happens when you click on Save Changes? Are you seeing any messages? Does it save successfully?

Comment: @cabrerahector I get the message: 'Permalink structure updated.'

Comment: Might be a server configuration issue. Check with your hosting provider if your setup meets the [requirements for "pretty" permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks).